# Present continuous when discussing photos

Tags: present-continuous

When I look at the photo, should I say

> The man at this photo **is reading** the book

or

> The man at this photo **reads** the book

Answer (score 2):

You would always use "in" to describe the location of the person in the photo, but yes. Either "The man in this photo is reading the book" or "The man in this photo reads the book" are valid. The first construction would be more common.

Comment: I would say it would be more common to say "the man in the photo is reading a book".

Comment: I think the difference between using "this" or "the" in this case is probably irrelevant to the question at hand...